# tool to observe the .NET Remoting communication between applications?

Tags: .net, windows, communication, .net-remoting, communication-protocol

We have problem with the communiction between two applications. According to the software providers, the communication is akind of .NET Remoting. We just want to verify which program first closes the communication, hopefully it could shed light for further debugging.
Is there any tool to facilitate the observation of .NET Remoting communication?

Comment: Is it "a kind of remoting" (which could mean anything), or is it ".NET Remoting" (a specific technology)? Also: ethereal/wireshark

Comment: @Marc Gravell It is about .NET Remoting. The two applications are running on one box/computer. Is there any links to configuration of wireshark for such cases?

Comment: To be onset, I think you would do better to just describe the actual problem you are seeing...

Comment: @Marc I'm software user instead of programmer of the two softwares. The two applications are simply black boxes for me. One application is observed to change one of its states which COULD be due to the .NET Remoting communication to the other application, but we don't have much experience on this technology.

Comment: That is a tricky problem and I don't have an easy answer for you. Even access to the network protocol won't make it easy t see what is *actually happening*. This sounds like a problem for the developer/vendor, with access to tools, debugging symbols, etc

Answer (score 0):

First: It isn't the end user's responsibility to figure this out: your software vendor(s) should be working together to figure out why these two applications are not communicating properly with one another.

My Answer: You can use Ethereal or Wireshark to monitor network connections and figure out which application is closing the network connection first.